# Is "throughout all this" correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, idiomatic-language

A man was in the hospital for 4 months because of sickness. In that time he didn't see his daughter. It's been a week since he came home from the hospital, and he has seen his daughter one time since then.

Woman: You're finally feeling well. Why aren't you more happy?

Man: Because I have a daughter I didn't see throughout all this.

- Is the man's statement correct and natural in the context?
- Is "throughout all this" correct to mean in the time where he was in the hospital?

Comment: She would probably *guess* that that was what he meant, but if it's now a week since he came home, 'throughout all this' rather suggests there is something still going on; 'throughout all that' would make it a bit more remote. His sentence would sound more natural as, 'Because I didn't see my daughter in all that time'. (By the way, we usually say 'once' rather than 'one time' and 'happier' rather than 'more happy'.)

Comment: If they have just talked about him being sick and in the hospital prior to this dialog, would that make 'this' seem more appropriate compared to 'that' or would that not change anything?

Comment: No, because their talk would all be in the past tense: in *that* time. The word 'this' would only work if he said something like, "Four months in hospital and now a week at home, and in all this time I've only seen her once."